# What do starred downloads mean in google code?

Tags: google-code

Besides expressing my interest in the download and being added to a counter, what other effects are there when starring a Google Code download file?

[Starred download http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/5161/googlecodestarreddownlo.png](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/5161/googlecodestarreddownlo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a download from Google Code - none, actually.  Starring a download really is just a way to indicate your interest in a particular download, compared to the others within a project.

For projects with a single release this isn't the most usable feature; for example, just because 500 users starred the last release while only 5 have done so on the latest may just mean that people haven't bothered to un-star the previous version.  For projects with multiple files - for example, a version with separate APIs for Windows, Mac, Linux, etc. - it could show which API is more favoured.

Unlike starring a project - which lists it in your favourites and list activity in your updates, or starring an issue that will send you updates when new comments are added (or showing your interest in said issue), there aren't any other benefits to starring a download, since new releases are typically added as separate downloads.